# How do you make a .hover delay in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider with thumbnails under the slides. I want to hover over the thumbnail image and change the slide. Is there a way to hover over a thumbnail img wait a second then change the slide to match the thumbnail?

```
    $(function(){

        $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

        $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
        $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

        $navthumb.hover(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            theInterval($this.parent().attr('id').slice(1) - 1);
            return false;
        } );

        theInterval();
    });
```

This is what I have and it works but it doesn't have a 1 second time lapse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$navthumb.hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.parent().attr('id').slice(1) - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return false;
} );
```

Comment: You left out the call to `theInterval()`.

Comment: The callback function should check whether you're still hovered over the element.

Comment: $navthumb.hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        theInterval($this.parent().attr('id').slice(1) - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return false;
} );

Comment: @Barmar Simpler to just clear the timeout in the hover out, but that was a bit out of scope of what he was asking.

Comment: @Barmar indeed, poor cat